# How to read data from xlsx in perl

Tags: perl, xlsx

Need a few good people help me with reading excel file with extension "xlsx" my script works for "xls" but not "xlsx", here is the code I get error: `Can't call method "worksheet" on an undefined value` if the file is "xlsx" here is the code I do have:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use warnings;
use strict;
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;
use Spreadsheet::XLSX;
use Date::Format;

my $filename = "../test.xlsx";
#Parse excel file
my $parser = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new();
my $workbook = $parser->parse("$filename");

#Get cell value from excel sheet1 row 1 column 2
my $worksheet = $workbook->worksheet('Sheet1');
my $cell = $worksheet->get_cell(0,1);

# Print the cell value when not blank
if ( defined $cell and $cell->value() ne "") {
    my $value = $cell->value();
    print "cell value is $value \n";
}
```

Comment: refer this https://github.com/jmcnamara/excel-reader-xlsx

Comment: @shankar "This project is effectively abandoned."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Spreadsheet::XLSX is an close equivalent of Spreadsheet::ParseExcel for .xlsx files; you need to say:

```
my $parser = Spreadsheet::XLSX->new();
```

instead of using ParseExcel.

Comment: [Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX) is a newer, more robust and featureful implementation.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use CPAN module [Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX](http://search.cpan.org/~doy/Spreadsheet-ParseXLSX-0.17/lib/Spreadsheet/ParseXLSX.pm) to parse `xlsx` files.

from documentation:

```
use Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX;

my $parser = Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX->new;
my $workbook = $parser->parse("file.xlsx");
```

see [Spreadsheet::ParseExcel](http://search.cpan.org/~dougw/Spreadsheet-ParseExcel-0.65/lib/Spreadsheet/ParseExcel.pm) for further documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have installed Spreadsheet::Read perl module which can determine the actual parser module to use for reading a file, below code fragments read and prints the cell of 1st worksheet of the input workbook. You can examine $workbook object to see all the options available to configure. This module can be used to read files in other formats like "csv", "xls" as well.  Here is the link to tutorial which I found to be useful:

http://search.cpan.org/~hmbrand/Spreadsheet-Read/Read.pm

```
use Spreadsheet::Read;
############################################################################
# function input  : file in xlsx format with absolute path 
# function output : prints 1st worksheet content if exist
############################################################################
sub print_xlsx_file{

    my $file_path = shift;
    my $workbook = ReadData($file_path,cells => 0 );
    if(defined $workbook->[0]{'error'}){
        print "Error occurred while processing $file_path:".
              $workbook->[0]{'error'}."\n";
        exit(-1);
    }
    my $worksheet = $workbook->[1];
    my $max_rows = $worksheet->{'maxrow'};
    my $max_cols = $worksheet->{'maxcol'};

    for my $row_num (1..($max_rows))
    {
        for my $col_num (1..($max_cols)){
            print $worksheet->{'cell'}[$col_num][$row_num]."\n";
        }
    }
}
# call above function
# print_xlsx_file("/home/chammu/mybook.xlsx");
```